# Bluetooth reconnect to last connected peripheral

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, reconnect

I use an Android central device to connect just one peripheral simultaneously. How can I reconnect to last connected peripheral when central detects its advertising again? What should I do to get this? Does Android needs to get peripheral device bonded?

I'm confused about `public BluetoothGatt connectGatt (Context context, boolean autoConnect, BluetoothGattCallback callback)`. I'm not sure if boolean `autoConnect`could be helpful, because doc. says:

> Whether to directly connect to the remote device (false) or to
>   automatically connect as soon as the remote device becomes available
>   (true).

"becomes available" is not clear for me. What does it mean?

Comment: Maria, what you wants to do exactly?

Comment: @pratik I want to reconnect an Android device (central) to the last connected peripheral after connection lost.

Answer (score 0):

In case this information could be useful for others, what I have finally done is starting a service that scans and connects to the last connected device address.

No idea what `autoConnect` parameter really does. I have try to connect setting this parameter to `true` and `false` values and I have not detect different performance.